# Meteor & JCrop: Issue trying to replicate a JCrop example

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I installed JCrop and tried to test it I got the JCrop pointer showing but it shows across the whole page instead of just over the image.  Also when selecting an area on the image you can't click and drag, the picture darkens just like the example at the link below but that's all.  It's not possible to select an area using my code.  Can't see anything I've done wrong.

This is what I'm trying to achieve (just to get started):

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial1.html

This is my template:

```
<template name="home">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Home content here</p>
          <img id="target" src="forrest.jpg" />
    </div>
</template>
```

The callback function to call when the template is rendered:

```
Template.home.rendered = function () {
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#target').Jcrop({
       trackDocument: true
    });
  });
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on this one?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Looks like a browser issue, works fine on FF but not on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing semi colon was the issue.  Code should be:

```
Template.home.rendered = function () {
  jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#target').Jcrop({
    trackDocument: true
   });
 });
};
```